# SQL novice question

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to solve the following problem. Suppose I have table T with three fields id, st(start time), fi (finish time) as following records (rows):

id  st   fi

1   2    5

1   4    11

1   5    9

2   7    13

I want to output one row per id having smallest start time (st). So the output should look like the following:

id  st   fi

1   2    5

2   7    13

What is the easiest way to write SQL query to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: are you using MySQL-8.0 or MariaDB-10.2+?

Comment: What you're describing is usually handled with `GROUP BY`.  This site is meant for relatively advanced database issues, like server configuration, database design, optimization, and complex queries; for basic SQL questions, you're better served by Stack Overflow.  Please be sure to search before you post; probably over 99% of questions a new student may have already have been asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure in MySQL but in postgres you could do something like

```
select distinct on (id) id, st, fi from tbl
order by id, st asc nulls last
```

Comment: This isn't correct [even on postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c04dff578f6cd8ff5a1e42ca9bdde5f4)

Comment: ah ok you're right. I was missing the initial order by column. The first order by column must match the distinct on column

Answer (score 1):

To get the minimum start in each group:

```
SELECT id,MIN(st) as st FROM tbl GROUP BY id
```

Then use join this to the original table to fetch all rows that have id,st

```
SELECT tbl.id,
       tbl.st,
       tbl.fi
FROM tbl
JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          MIN(st) AS st
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY id) mins ON tbl.id=mins.id
AND tbl.st=mins.st
```

Note if you have the same `st` for an `id` multiple times you will get all the minimum `st` time rows.

Comment: Thank you. This is simple and elegant.